# Mobile number validation issue with google i18 package

Tags: scala

I am using google i18 package

```
package com.google.i18n.phonenumbers;
```

```
 private val mobileRule = genValidation("mobile", _.notificationChannels.find(_.channel == "mobile").forall { channel =>
      channel.channelId.exists(number => !numberUtil.isValidNumber(numberUtil.parse(number, "GB")))
    }, "the mobile number entered is not valid or has not been entered")
    
    private val landlineRule = genValidation("landline", _.notificationChannels.find(_.channel == "landline").exists { channel =>
      channel.channelId.exists(number => !numberUtil.isValidNumber(numberUtil.parse(number, "GB")))
    }, "the landline number entered is not valid")
```

With this i18 package if i pass a 17 digit mobile number then it accept otherwise it gives me 500 error can somebody help me on that so that if i pass greater than digit 10 it gives me some type of error like mobile number is incorrect.

With the above code If I pass less than 10 then gives me error that is mobile number is incorrect which is fine but I want if i pass greater then 10 also in that case it gives me 500 error.

Please help if anyone have idea.

Comment: I believe you have issue in landline code: `private val landlineRule = genValidation("landline", _.notificationChannels.find(_.channel == "landline").forall  { channel =>
      channel.channelId.exists(number => !numberUtil.isValidNumber(numberUtil.parse(number, "GB")))
    }, "the landline number entered is not valid")`

Try this.

Comment: No not that a issue I have already tried that I have to check the 10 digit for both

Comment: I am saying replace `(_.channel == "landline").exists` with `(_.channel == "landline").forall`. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you should convert the number from 10 digits to 15 digits  E.164.
E.164 is the international telephone numbering plan that ensures each device on the PSTN has globally unique number.

This number allows phone calls and text messages can be correctly routed to individual phones in different countries. E.164 numbers are formatted [+] [country code] [subscriber number including area code] and can have a maximum of fifteen digits.
Examples of E.164 Numbers
E.164 Format

Country Code
Country

Subscriber Number

+14155552671

1

US

4155552671

+442071838750

44

GB

2071838750

+551155256325

55

BR

1155256325

```
public static String formatE164(String countryCode, String number) {
  try {
    PhoneNumberUtil util     = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
    int parsedCountryCode    = Integer.parseInt(countryCode);
    PhoneNumber parsedNumber = util.parse(number,
                                          util.getRegionCodeForCountryCode(parsedCountryCode));

    return util.format(parsedNumber, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.E164);
  } catch (NumberParseException | NumberFormatException npe) {
    Log.w(TAG, npe);
  }

  return "+"                                                     +
      countryCode.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "").replaceAll("^0*", "") +
      number.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
}
```